# Is $T_1$ space on a infinite set necessarily a finite closed topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

It seemed to me that $T_1$ space on an infinite set is necessarily a finite closed topology. I built a proof for it.

Let, $S$ be an infinite set and $(\mathscr P,S)$ be a $T_1$ space on this infinite set.  We have to show that $\mathscr P$ is also a finite closed topology.

Let, $A$ be any finite subset of $S$, such that: $A=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots,x_n\}$.
Then, every singleton subset of $S$ is closed in $\mathscr P$. So $S\setminus\{x_i\}$ is open on $\mathscr P$.
But, $\mathscr P$ is a topology, so the intersection of any finite number of subsets is open on $\mathscr P$.
So $\bigcap_{i=1}^n(S\setminus\{x_i\})=S\setminus\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}=S\setminus A$ is open.

So, it can be shown that any finite subset of $S$ is closed on $\mathscr P$.
Therefore, $\mathscr P$ is a finite closed topology. And $T_1$ space on a infinite set is finite closed topology.

Is my proof watertight?

Comment: $S$ need not be infinite in fact. Your proof also works for finite $S$.

Comment: Your proof looks fine: indeed being finite closed is equivalent to being $T_1$.

Comment: Sure this is fine. It might be more usual to think of (1) "T1 implies finite sets are closed" as being a consequence of the axiom (2) "finite unions of closed sets are closed" which is equivalent to the dual axiom (3) "finite intersections of open sets are open". In fact, your proof of (1) basically contains the proof that (2) implies (3). Certainly there is no problem with this, but at some point you will want to switch over to thinking of (2) as a basic fact.

Comment: @Mockingbird360, your proof is not complete. You proved that (a) any finite set is closed (finite => closed). But in order to show that topology is finite closed you also have to prove that (b) any closed set is finite (closed => finite). Counterexample: what if your topology has closed set which is infinite? Then combining (a) and (b) together you can say that finite sets are the only that are closed (finite <=> closed)